# Display date only and no time in Android

Tags: android, date

I am attempting to display a date in android with year, month, and day chosen using a DatePicker. What I'm having trouble with is taking the year, month, and day chosen and displaying them on the screen in the correct format for the locale of the phone without also displaying the time.

The code as it stands now will display the date correctly but it also displays the time.

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
    .append(mYear).append("-")
    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
    .append(mDay);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {   
        Date date = format.parse(string.toString());
        mDateDisplay.setText(date.toLocaleString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

mDateDisplay is a TextView.

I can't figure out how to get rid of the time that is also displayed. I've done a fair amount of searching and reading documentation and I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getContext());
mDateDisplay.setText(dateFormat.format(date))
```

This will take into account the users locale settings and only display the date.

Here is the relevant documentation: [getDateFormat(Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
df.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date());
```

or

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date());
```

refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)

**Updated**::

you can also use [formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) to get only date as below::

```
mDateDisplay.setText(String.format("%1$tY %1$tb %1$td", date));
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the locale of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat timeonly = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);
        String timeString = timeonly.format(date);
        //show present date
        textView.setText(dateString);

        //show present time
        TextView.setText(timeString);
```

Answer (score 0):

i spend hour on this, finally a found solution.

```
 String datemillis = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("field name on table"));
            SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");



            try {
                Date date = null;
                date = df.parse(datemillis);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String shortTimeStr = sdf.format(date);
                System.out.println(shortTimeStr);
                Y=shortTimeStr;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt, txt1;

Button click;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String f=df.format(c.getTime());

            txt1.setText(f);
        }
    });       
}

}
```